# Who set the standard for IO port numbers

Tags: io, x86, operating-system, osdev

I know i can control the IDE hard disk by I/O port (0x1f0~0x1f7)，8259A(0x20H-0x3FH),

so I'm curious about who set these standards and where I can find all the IO port numbers

Comment: For a table [look here @ OSDev](https://wiki.osdev.org/I/O_Ports#The_list).

Comment: IBM made most of the choices for the IBM PC.  Everything later just chose to be compatible with it.  And decades later we still have hardware carrying around that baggage, or emulating parts of it with system-management mode.  (Not a major burden for most hardware, I think, although making CPUs run x86 machine code has downsides.)

Comment: There may be some stuff on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibm-pc, for example [How does the BIOS distinguish Interrupt(08h-12h) from INT instructions, vs. actual exceptions inside the CPU?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/24552) about IBM's poor design choice for software interrupt numbers that conflict with IRQ and reserved exception numbers.